# Image being loaded a second time to be displayed in showcase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

in react my project a product can have multiple images, those images are displayed on the product's page in a showcase component, where the user can click on an image to display it as main image like in the picture below

[image]

i've noticed an issue when the main image changes that the browser would "hang" for a second or two until it changes the main image, i monitored the network activity on chrome browser and found nothing. but when i tried this with firefox i saw that the image is being loaded a second time, which is consuming more time and resources..how can i prevent this from happening? here is my image showcase component's code, i'm using react.js with bootstrap 5

```
//{images} is an array that contains images' addresses
function ProductImageShowCase({ images }) {
    let [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState(0);
    let imagesContainer = useRef();

    

    return (
        <div className="w-80 mx-auto border border-main shadow rounded p-1">
            <div className="w-100 mb-2 px-5 py-2">
                <img src={images[activeImage]} width="100%" height="400px" />
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div onClick={scrollLefts} className="arrow-container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center cursor-pointer">
                    <i className="bi bi-chevron-left text-main fs-1"></i>
                </div>

                <div ref={imagesContainer} className="text-center py-4" style={{ overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "nowrap", scrollBehavior: "smooth" }}>
                    {images.map((image, i) => {
                        return <img key={image} src={image} className={`mx-4 product-images-showcase ${i == activeImage ? "active-image" : ""}`} onClick={() => { setActiveImage(i) }} width={100} height={100} />
                    })}
                </div>

                <div onClick={scrollRights} className="arrow-container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center cursor-pointer">
                    <i className="bi bi-chevron-right text-main fs-1"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```